# INNER JOIN involving RAND(...NEWID()) returns unexpected number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, sql-server-2019

I want to generate some sample data with random values.

I have a mini table with 5 rows, ids from 1 to 5 with some text for every row.

Then I want to generate 65536 rows - first column has value 1 for every row, second column is random number between 1 and 5, without NULL values.

Then I want to join these two tables. With `ROW_NUMBER() % 5` approach `INNER/OUTER JOIN` returns 65536 rows.

Instead of this pseudo random column I want to use `RAND` seeded by `NEWID`.

`LEFT JOIN` returns 65536 rows as I suspected, but `INNER JOIN` returns different row count for every call.

When `LFINAL` table is materialized into temp table, then `INNER JOIN` works and returns 65536 rows too.

Can somebody explain to me why `INNER JOIN` does not return 65536 rows as I expected?

```
WITH Names AS 
(
    SELECT id, row_name 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 1, 'Row 1' UNION ALL 
         SELECT 2, 'Row 2' UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Row 3' UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'Row 4' UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 'Row 5') AS D (id, row_name)
),
L0 AS 
(
    SELECT c 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)
),  --2^1
L1 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS c 
    FROM L0 AS A 
    CROSS JOIN L0 AS B
),          --2^2
L2 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS c 
    FROM L1 AS A 
    CROSS JOIN L1 AS B
),          --2^4
L3 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS c 
    FROM L2 AS A 
    CROSS JOIN L2 AS B
),          --2^8
L4 AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS c 
    FROM L3 AS A 
    CROSS JOIN L3 AS B
),          --2^16 = 65536
LFINAL AS 
(
    SELECT 
        c, 
        --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c) % 5 + 1 AS rnd FROM L4)
        FLOOR(RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY, NEWID()))*5) + 1 AS rnd 
    FROM 
        L4
)
SELECT * 
FROM LFINAL lf
LEFT JOIN Names n ON n.id = lf.rnd
```

Comment: *" but INNER JOIN returns different row count for every call"* Less, I assume (you don't tell us). If so, the reason is clear; some of the `JOIN`s failed to find a related row and so less rows were returned.

Comment: for inner join you get different rows.

Comment: Change LEFT to INNER - even more rows than 65536 can be returned if you run query several times..

Comment: My row count with inner join = 65659, 65743, 65374, 65398, 65825, 65491, 65374. I think that this will be some bug in SQL optimalizator.

Comment: I am using WIN 10 PRO 21H2 with last patches and SQL 2019 developer with last paches, concrete versions are: OS build 19044.1566, Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0, SQL 2019 15.0.2080.9

Comment: Per Salman's answer, this is not a bug and it's not going to be fixed. The optimizer does not guarantee every row in a CTE is evaluated only once, since they're interpolated into the query as though they were subqueries. That means using non-deterministic expressions can have unexpected results which will depend on the execution plan chosen. As an aside, a shorter and probably better way of generating a random number is `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) % 5 + 1` (though note this is still non-deterministic).

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's basically dependent on the shape of the execution plan. It is *possible* it would only be invoked once, but it's possible it won't, and as you say there is no guarantee either way. I have had cases where small changes to a query can make an arbitrary difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem. ***This should be the expected behavior because***:

- The `newid()` is not generated per row, it is generated per invocation
- The optimizer is free to evaluate a row more than once

When tested, SQL server seems to do the following behind the scenes:

```
for (row 1 ... 5 in dbo.names)
    for (row 1 ... 65536 in lfinal)
        add the pair {dbo.names.id, rand(newid...) as rnd} to selection
filter (where dbo.names.id = rnd)
```

Notice that each row from the set of 327680 rows has 20% probability of matching the filter. You will get *around* 65536 rows in total but not *exactly* that many.

I would suggest inserting the random numbers into a temporary table (variable) so that the numbers are materialized, then join.