# SQL query to update a column from another column randomly without any condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Note : Table B size is smaller than Table A. Null is not allowed while updating data in table A.

I want to update the table A column 'postcode' by randomly select an 'Element' from the table 'B' then add a space, a random number and 2 random letters.

For Example:

Table A

```
ID   postcode
1     ABC 1GH
2     CDE 2MH
3     SAD 6GK
4     GOD 2UO
```

Table B

```
ID  ELEMENT
1   FJL
2   WHO
3   HPS
```

Expected Output in TABLE A
( RANDOM Element from Table B followed by space followed by random single digit number followed by 2 alphabets)

```
ID Postcode
1  WHO 8GH
2  HPS 2UI
3  FJL 4YT[7:40 PM] Prasanna, Prashanth (Proagrica-CON)
```

My present query :

```
update tableA
set postcode = A.element + ' ' +
cast((abs(convert(bigint, rndord)) % 9) as char(1))
+ char(65 + abs(convert(bigint, substring(rndord, 9, 4))) % (90-65))
+ char(65 + abs(convert(bigint, substring(rndord, 13, 4))) % (90-65))
from tableB b
inner join
(SELECT *, convert(varbinary(16), NEWID(), 1) rndord,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS SNO
FROM tableB) AS original on original.BrickId = b.brickid
inner JOIN
(SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS SNO
, element
FROM tableB) AS A ON original.SNO =A.SNO
```

This updates only few columns and other columns are untouched.

Comment: What does table A have to do with the question?

Comment: "followed by two _letters_".

Comment: I, too, wonder how table A comes into play here. Do you want to remove all rows from table A and fill the table with the generated rows from table B instead? Or are there more or less rows in table A than in B and you want to keep the same amount of rows in table A, but their comtent t be generated from table B rows? And one more question: If we unfortunately happened to randomly create three rows that all look the same in your example, say, 1  WHO 8GH, 2  WHO 8GH, and 2  WHO 8GH, would that still be okay? Or is there any additional rule we must obey?

Comment: I want to obfuscate the data in table A.  So I want to update the table A by randomly selecting the element from table B and add a space to it followed by random single digit number and random 2 alphabets.

Comment: See if the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378946/inner-join-involving-rand-newid-returns-unexpected-number-of-rows applies to your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>First of all we must be sure that cardinality of `TableB` **MUST BE** greater than or equal to cardinality of `TableA`.</s>

After the **EDIT** we assume that cardinality of `TableB` can also be smaller than cardinality of `TableA`, so we 1st need to multiply `TableB` rows enough to be more then `TableA` rows (tables `Cnt` and `numbers`) and then use the `numbers` table in `TblB` to multiply the rows.

In this mode, `ELEMENT` could be repeated across rows, but random part will be different.

We need to add a random info to `TableB` that will be used both to obfuscate `ELEMENT` and to shuffle the order. For this purpose we will add a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column with random values from `NEWID()` function.

To shuffle the order we will number `TableA.ID` and the new random column in `TableB`
adding a sort of *interface* between them.

To obfuscate `ELEMENT` we will strip portions of our random info.

```
;with
Cnt as (
    select cast(ceiling(1.0*CntA.cnt/CntB.cnt) as int) Btimes
    from 
        (select count(*) cnt from TableA) CntA, 
        (select count(*) cnt from TableB) CntB
),
numbers as (
        select top((select Btimes from cnt)) ROW_NUMBER() over (order by object_id) n
        from sys.objects
),
TblB as (
    SELECT *, convert(varbinary(16), NEWID(), 1) rndord
    FROM TableB, numbers
),
TableAx as (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) idx
    FROM TableA
),
TableBx as (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by rndord) idx
    FROM TblB
)
select a.id, ELEMENT + ' ' +
    cast((abs(convert(bigint, rndord)) % 9) as char(1))
    + char(65 + abs(convert(bigint, substring(rndord, 9, 4))) % (90-65)) 
    + char(65 + abs(convert(bigint, substring(rndord, 13, 4))) % (90-65)) postcode
from TableAx a 
left join TableBx b on a.idx = b.idx
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Hi, my table B size is smaller than table A. So I want all columns in table A to be updated with random data from table B . could you please reframe the query ?

Comment: @john so in your output you can have the same random element from B in different rows of A?

Comment: yes I can have same random element from B as well but all element should not be same.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the quick solution :) brilliant stuff !

Answer (score 1):

You can use below

```
select ELEMENT + ' ' + convert(varchar(1),ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2)) + char(cast((90 - 65 )*rand() + 65 as integer))+ char(cast((90 - 65 )*rand() + 65 as integer))
FROM B
```

Comment: I tried this using the update query. I get all columns with similar values.

Comment: `rand` is evaluated only once, so every row will get similar obfuscation